# Creating OSGi bundles with different services

Tags: java, maven, osgi, maven-plugin, day-cq

We are using Adobe Day CQ for our deployment. We are currently creating OSGi bundles with gets deployed in CQ with all the services using maven-bundle-plugin.

Now we have a scenario  where we do not want some services to get enabled in Publish instance but should be enabled in Author.

Is there a way where we can manage two bundles one for author with the services required for author and one for publish which are required on publish, using the same pom.xml ?
Or else is there any other way by which this thing can me managed.
Please help me in this regard.
We are right now using this for creating bundles:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.osgi.framework,
                        *;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                          com.abc.platform.enow.aem.core.testing.*,
                        com.abc.platform.enow.aem.core.utils.*,
                    com.abc.platform.enow.aem.core.viewhelper.*,
                        com.abc.platform.enow.aem.core.search.*

                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please help me in this context ... I am not able to find the option anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have achieved this by using the runmode property for CQ.
We did the below:

- Created the full build.
- In the distribution phase we pushed the jar (that we required to install only on author) to the folder /apps/"project_name"/install.author.
- Here "author" is the run mode for the instance.
- This jar deploys to both author and publish in the folder install.author but in installed / reflected only on the author mode.

Thanks for the reply, but we found this solution more flexible and feasible.

Regards,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. The first approach would be preferable

### Selective activation via Configuration

You can achieve that by using Sling Run Mode based Configuration support and using Declarative Services for managing service registration.

**Bind your service to Configuration**

Use SCR annotation to bind your service to configuration

```java
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ConfigurationPolicy;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;


@Component(
    name = FooImpl.SERVICE_PID,
    policy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
@Service
public class FooImpl implements IFoo{
  public static final String SERVICE_PID = "com.foo.example";
```

In above code snippet we

- Register a service which implements `IFoo` interface
- `ConfigurationPolicy` for the component is set to `REQUIRE` i.e. without any explicit configuration the component and thus the service would not be activated and registered
- The PID of the config is set to `com.foo.example`. If you omit it then it default to fully qualified name of the class

**Create config under the required Run Mode folder**

In CQ the Sling installer would deploy configuration and bundle from the repository based on the Run Mode. So if you are deploying your code via Content Packages then

- Create a [config node](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#Creating%20the%20Configuration%20in%20the%20Repository) under path `/apps/<yourProject>/config.author/com.foo.example`
- Under above path just create a blank ode (unless you want to provide other config properties) of type `sling:OsgiConfig`

With above changes done deploy your content package on various CQ instances

- When package is deploy on any CQ instance then Configuration for PID `com.foo.example` would only be created when the run mode is set to Author
- And only when configuration is active then only `FooImpl` component and service would be created and registered

### Using SlingSettingsService

Another approach can make use of the [SlingSettingsService.getRunModes](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/settings/SlingSettingsService.html#getRunModes%28%29) to determine the run mode programatically and then only register the service.

```java
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;

@Component
public class FooImpl implements IFoo{

    @Reference
    private SlingSettingsService settingsService;

    private ServiceRegistration reg;

    @Activate
    public void activate(BundleContext context, Map<String, ?> conf){
        if(settingsService.getRunModes().contains("author")){
           reg = context.registerService(IFoo.class.getName(), this, null);
        }
    }

    @Deactivate
    private void deactivate(){
        if (reg != null){
            reg.unregister();
        }
    }
}
```

Couple of points to note for above snippet

- `FooImpl` is not annotated with `@Service` tag. So SCR would only activate the component but would not register any service
- In `activate` method we use `SlingSettingsService` to check for required run mode. In case it is `author` we programatically register the service
- Service instance is removed later in the `deactivate` method

Comment: Hi Chetan, This is a very good help. will give a try to this. Can you please let me know if there is a way by which this can happen using the project's pom.xml as it will be easier instead of making changes to the code.